# Having trouble correctly creating JWT for google service account auth

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, jwt, google-authentication

I'm trying to create a script on [scriptr.io](http://scriptr.io) that creates a [JWT/JWS](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to send to google's token endpoint in order to get an `auth_token` for my service account. I'm using the [CryptoJS library](https://github.com/caffeinatedMike/CryptoJS) in order to do the encrypting. I'm able to generate all 3 parts of the JWT, but I'm doing something wrong when doing so. I believe it has something to do with the last of the three parts of the string (so, the signature part), but I could be wrong.

```
var cryptoJs = {};
cryptoJs['SHA256'] = require('CryptoJS/rollups/sha256.js').CryptoJS.SHA256

var pHeader = {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
var sHeader = JSON.stringify(pHeader);
var encodedHeader = Base64EncodeUrl(btoa(sHeader));
console.log("encodedHeader: " + encodedHeader);

var now = new Date();
var oneHourExpiration = ((now.getTime()-now.getMilliseconds())/1000)+3000;//3000, not 3600 which is 1 hour

var pClaim = {};
pClaim.iss = "-------@---iam.gserviceaccount.com";
pClaim.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets";
pClaim.aud = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
pClaim.exp = oneHourExpiration;
pClaim.iat = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
console.log("exp: " + pClaim.exp);
console.log("iat: " + pClaim.iat);

var sClaim = JSON.stringify(pClaim);
var encodedClaim = Base64EncodeUrl(btoa(sClaim));
console.log("encodedClaim: " + encodedClaim);

var byteArray = encodedHeader + "." + encodedClaim;
console.log("byteArray: " + byteArray);

var secret = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n.....MIIE.....=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
var signature = cryptoJs.SHA256(byteArray, secret);
var encodedSignature = Base64EncodeUrl(btoa(signature));
console.log("Encoded Signature: " + encodedSignature);

var sJWS = byteArray + "." + encodedSignature;
console.log("JWT: " + sJWS);

function Base64EncodeUrl(str){
    return str.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, '');
}

var http = require("http");
var requestObject = {
  "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
  "params": {"grant_type":"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer","assertion":sJWS}
}


var response = http.request(requestObject);
var responseBodyStr = response.body;
console.log(responseBodyStr);
var token = JSON.parse(responseBodyStr.access_token);
console.log(token);
```

When I send the request to the token endpoint with the JWT I get the following response

```
{  
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
 }
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Can someone help me correctly format the JWT so I can get a token?

Answer (score 1):

The function used is doing a hash, not a digital signature

```
var signature = cryptoJs.SHA256(byteArray, secret);
```

Digital signature with a RSA private key is not supported . Take a look at the comment in the main repository of [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/)

> **Inactivity**
>
> CryptoJS is a project that I enjoy and work on in my spare time, but
>   unfortunately my 9-to-5 hasn't left me with as much free time as it
>   used to. I'd still like to continue improving it in the future, but I
>   can't say when that will be. If you find that CryptoJS doesn't meet
>   your needs, then I'd recommend you try Forge.

I suggest to move the code to use other Javascript library like recommended. For example forge support RSA signatures (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa)

---

Google OAuth2 server uses **RS256**. I have provided an snippet to convert the secret key (I assumed PEM format) to forge and sign data using RSA with SHA256

> The only signing algorithm supported by the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server is RSA using SHA-256 hashing algorithm. This is expressed as RS256 in the alg field in the JWT header.

```
// convert a PEM-formatted private key to a Forge private key
var privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(pem);

// sign data with a private key and output DigestInfo DER-encoded bytes (defaults to RSASSA PKCS#1 v1.5)
var md = forge.md.sha256.create();
md.update(byteArray, 'utf8');
var signature = privateKey.sign(md);

//convert signature to base64
var encodedSignature = Base64EncodeUrl(btoa(signature));
```

Comment: By chance could you provide an example of how to sign (according to google's specificarions) with the library you've provided?

Comment: Also, is this a node library? If so, I will not be able to use it as I can only use plain javascript

Comment: forge is a javascript library (like cryptoJS and others). Can be used both in server&client side. Could you post or point me to the exact requirements of Google's JWT signature? Seems you have to use RS256 with a private key in PEM format (`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`)

Comment: You can find the exact requirements for the google signature in the link of my post (click the text JWT/JWS)

Comment: Also, I should mention the library needs to work headless because scriptr.io doesn't have access to a document/window object

Comment: If you'd be willing to help, I could provide my secret key and info via email

Comment: Seems your secret key it is in PEM format. Forge has support for it. Take a look at the code snippet. I have not tested it, but it should work. You will need to download and build forge.js

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Now I just to figure out how to install forge on scriptr

Comment: I've been trying to use this example, but it will not work because the modules are node.js. I'm referring to the md.js and forge.js files. The only one that is pure javascript is the pki.js. Can we chat to see if you can help me get it working?

Comment: You can build forge for node.js or as plain javascript for web browser. In the documentation you can find how to build it or download a prebundled version

Comment: Since I need to accomplish this on scriptr.io the script doesn't have access to a window/document object like javascript that's executed from within html. Mind chatting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134798/discussion-between-caffeinatedcoder-and-pedrofb).